# php mysql loop memory leaks?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, out-of-memory

My php script stop running because it goes out of memory.
Here is my code:

```
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir_name), array('..', '.'));
if (!empty($files))
{
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "csv")
        {
            $fp = fopen($dir_name.$file, 'r');
            while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
                insert_update(array_map('addslashes', $line), $connect_id);
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($connect_id);
}
```

I did run the script like 4 times on the same csv (more than 600k rows).
And with exactly the same script it stop at different moments...
Number of request done before it stop : 205 286 // 200 514 // 192 429 // 211 164
(I truncate the table before each try).
I used always the same variables... how the memory used can increase ? 
Its only a foreach loop... if its work once, it should work unlimited times, right ?

Thank you,

Mickael.

PS: Here is my function 'insert_update'

```
function insert_update($row, $connect_id)
{
    $table_name = "xxxxxxxx";
    $maxcol = 42;

    $my_request = "INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES ('$row[0]'";
    $i = 1;
    while ($i < $maxcol)
    {
        if (isset($row[$i]))
            $my_request = $my_request.", '$row[$i]'";
        else
            $my_request = $my_request.", ''";
        $i++;
    }
    $my_request = $my_request.")";
    if (mysqli_query($connect_id, $my_request) == FALSE)
    {
        echo "<p>$my_request</p>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). `addslashes()` is utterly useless garbage and is NOT useful in protecting yourself. it's a condom made out of wire mesh

Comment: are the files coming back in the same order each time? if not then that should explain why the two different stops.... also maybe just increase memory available and move on :)   ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

Comment: -MarcB Ok but all the CSV files are secured.
-myte For the test i just used one csv, and i truncate the table after each test.. any others idea about how it can stop at different moments ? 'memory_limit' is set at '-1'.
And more importante, any idea for why it stop at all ?

Comment: @Marc B, thanks for painting that visual, `addslashes()` is *exactly* like a wire mesh condom. That should be in the documentation.

Comment: @Mickael_42: doesn't matter. external data going into a query string is an injection vulnerability. doesn't matter if it's a "secured" file or not: you can EASILY injection yourself. addslashes may make you feel warm and fuzzy, but it's useless for anything but the most obvious injection methods.

Comment: @MarcB I used addslashes just to treat name like O'Neil correctly in my data... Nothing about security.
But still, thank you for the advice, its always good to know. Do you also have any advice for my 'stop running' issue ?

Comment: and that's the problem. addslashes is basically `str_replace("'", "\'")`. it doesn't handle unicode, and unicode sequences can get corrupted by addslashes to lead to an injection vulnerability.

Comment: as for the stop problem: done any debugging like putting calls to `memory_get_usage()` into the code, and turning on display_errors/error_reporting? If you ARE running out of memory due to leaks, you should see usage climbing continuously, followed by an "out of memory" error/abort.

Comment: @MarcB Yes i'm using memory_get_usage() but the values just up/down at +- 1k memory only.. So leaks obviously.
What should i use instead of addslashes ? cause it work well in my case...

Comment: at least mysql_real_escape_string(). better yet would be to ditch the entire mysql_*() function set and switch to mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements. then you don't have to build the same query over and over and over. build the query ONCE, bind your parametesr, then just execute over and over.

Comment: @MarcB I do use mysqli. I'll check for mysql_real_escape_string() thank for the advice.

Comment: Ok got it, the loop was 'too fast' so my script stop because the server wasnt supported too many request in the same time.
I add usleep(50) and it work perfectly fine.

Thank you all again.

Comment: woops, right on the mysqli. sorry. nasty headache today. you'd need mysqli_real_escape_string() then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function does not contain statics and should not leave anything behind. Your loop also does not keep anything in RAM. So, if you didnt accidently discover any memory_leaks in the used PHP functions,
another issue might be the garbage collector. This service frees no longer used memory. THis garbage collector does not run after each variable id freed but in it's own time frame.

You can however try to force the garbage collector to free memory now. (Some people say it wont affect memory as. Dunno)

```
gc_collect_cycles()
```

Some debugging may also help you identify the source of the leak:

```
memory_get_peak_usage();
```

You can also try to increase the memory limit for this script. This shuldnt be done on a public available file however as it may take up all of your server memory fast then.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Another option might be to try different methods of file access and db connection depending on what's available to you.

If all else fails, create some kind of iteration. Process 10 files, then redirect to your script with a offset parameter to start from where you left off last time. Repeat until all files are processed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php

Comment: Thank you for your help. The fact is that when i check the memory used at each iteration, the memory increase each time and i cant find why.

Comment: Measure memory on more and more lines until you find the one line that increases it most. Maybe you can at least experiment with alternative logic then.

Comment: Is there no specific line that increase most than others.

Comment: All of your code looks as if it should free memory after each line and never pile up anything. So I think some of your used functions are bad in cleaning up after themselves. My guess is either fget_csv or mysqli_query. probably the later.